# Rewrite all URIs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have pages like this:
www.domain.com/name-of-page.php

I would like it to work and appear as www.domain.com/name-of-page/ instead

This is what I've got, it doesn't seem to work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: How about make a directory for all "name-of-page" pages.
and make an index.php file of those directory.
next you can redirect "name-of-page.php" to directory "name-of-page".

Comment: Ah that would be difficult to implement, especially as there are many relative links. I was hoping there would be a way to use htaccess rewrite